# How do I add and subtract months from a date?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add/subtract an integer to the element of array. my function is

```
var addToMonth = function (date, monthsToAdd) {
    var tempDate = date.split("-");
    tempDate[1] = parseInt(tempDate[1]) + monthsToAdd;
    tempDate[1] = 0 + tempDate[1];
    console.log("TempDate "+tempDate[1]);
    tempDate = tempDate.join("-");
    console.log("Added TempDate: "+tempDate);
    return tempDate;
}
```

The acceptable date string is: `date = "2016-04-05"`. If call the function as `addToMonth(date,1)`. The output is correct that is `2016-05-05`. But when I call it as `addToMonth(date, -1)`. It doesn't work. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: What is not working? You getting errors?

Comment: This seems to work fine. Is your problem with padding the month with `0`?

Comment: `tempDate[1] =  '' + 0 + tempDate[1];` to pad it with `0`..Rest of things look good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original 2016**

The selected answer is actually incorrect as the question asks how to add months, not days. The correct solution is:

```
   function addToMonth( date, months ) {
        var d = new Date( date || new Date() );
        d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + (months || 0), d.getDate());
        return d;      
    }
```

**Show and then run the code snippet to view demo.**

I've also up voted the question ... because it does show effort and dates are tricky to work with even for experienced coders (especially when time zones are involved). That's why there are libraries like [monment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and others. For more information on the Date object see: [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
function addToMonth( date, months ) {
    var d = new Date( date || new Date() );
    d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + (months || 0), d.getDate());
    return d;      
}


// Test Data
var html = '', iso, step = 1;


[
  '4/5/2016',
  '4/5/2016 01:00 GMT', 
  '2016-04-05', 
  '2016-04-05T00:00:00', 
  '2016-04-05T23:59:59',
  '2016-04-05T23:59:59Z',
  '2016', 
  '4/5/2016',
  undefined, 
  null, 
  0, 
  '',
  (new Date())

].forEach(function(v,i) {
  iso = addToMonth( v, -1).toISOString().split('T').shift();
  html += '<tr><td>' + v + '</td><td>-1</td><td>' + iso + '</td></tr>';
  iso = addToMonth( v, 1).toISOString().split('T').shift();
  html += '<tr><td>' + v + '</td><td>+1</td><td>' + iso + '</td></tr>';


});

stdout.innerHTML = '<table>' + html + '</table>';
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}
td {
  max-width: 10em;
  min-width: 4em;
  border: 1px lightgray solid;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="stdout"></div>
```

**Update 2023**

A commenter noted the edge case where the day of the month is greater than the target maximum. In this case the function uses the default [Date.setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth#description) behavior, which can spill over into the following month, e.g., 31 Jan + 1 month = 3 Mar rather than 28 Feb. Since the question doesn't specify how to handle these cases it seems reasonable to use the expected behavior and not try to guess what OP wants.

The commenter also noted that `getDate` is redundant in

```
d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + (months || 0), d.getDate())
```

True, and it can be shortened to

```
d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + (months || 0))
```

Interestingly, this change didn't appear to make any difference in performance (Chrome 100k loops).

**Alternative code that incorporates commenter suggestions:**

```
function addToMonth( date, months ) {
  let d = new Date( date || new Date() ), n = d.getDate(); 
  d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + (months || 0));
  if (d.getDate() < n) d.setMonth( d.getMonth(), 0);
  return d;      
}
```

Comment: In the statement `d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + (months || 0), d.getDate())`, the expression `d.getDate()` is entirely redundant as that's the default anyway. It also doesn't address the issue of adding one month where the day doesn't exist in the resulting month (e.g. 31 Jan + 1 month gives 31 Feb which resolves to 2 or 3 Mar).

Answer (score 1):

Yours is not a right approach:

1. `parseInt` should always use base 10 if working with decimals.
2. `addToMonth("2016-31-03", 1)` will give *2016-32-03*. WRONG X.
3. `addToMonth("2016-01-03", -1)` will give *2016-00-03*. WRONG X.
4. The way you are padding the `0` is not right. (Find out why.)

Use `setDate` and `getDate` functions on **date** instead.

```
var addToMonth = function (date, monthsToAdd) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+monthsToAdd);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: If we use OP's test case 'addToMonth("2016-04-05")' this code returns 2016-04-06 whereas the expected result is 2016-05-06.